# Add loop/exit logic so that any input collected could be repeated or user could exit the program

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to write a code that asks a user for input then asks the user if they would like to repeat the sequence for each sequence [Y/N]. If I type Y, it will repeat but if I type "N" it will not move to the next question and I cant get it to do it for the remaining parts. I also need to be able to have the option to exit each part.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
*
 * 
 */
  public class AssignmentWeek11 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
 public static void main(String args[]) {

 NewClass account1 = new NewClass("Brian", 50.00);

 NewClass account2 = new NewClass("Cosmo Kramer", -7.53);

   System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2f%n", account1.getName(), 
  account1.getBalance());
   System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2f%n%n", account2.getName(), 
  account2.getBalance());

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


   String repeat = "Y";

while(repeat.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){     
   System.out.println("Enter deposit amount for account1: ");
   double depositAmount = input.nextDouble();


   System.out.println("Adding " + depositAmount + " to account1 balance");
   account1.deposit(depositAmount);


  System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2f%n", account1.getName(), account1.getBalance());
   System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2f%n%n", account2.getName(), account2.getBalance());
   System.out.print("Would you like to try again? [Y/N]");
        repeat = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println(repeat);
}  

   System.out.println("Enter deposit amount for account2: ");
   depositAmount = input.nextDouble();

   System.out.println("Adding " + depositAmount + " to account2 balance");
   account2.deposit(depositAmount);

   System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2f%n", account1.getName(), account1.getBalance());
   System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2f%n%n", account2.getName(), account2.getBalance());


   System.out.println("Enter withdrawl amount for account1: ");
   double withdrawlAmount = input.nextDouble();

   System.out.println("Withdrawing " + withdrawlAmount + " from account1 balance....");
   account1.withdraw(withdrawlAmount);

   System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2f%n", account1.getName(), account1.getBalance());
   System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2f%n%n", account2.getName(), account2.getBalance());

   System.out.println("Enter withdrawl amount for account2: ");
   withdrawlAmount = input.nextDouble();

   System.out.println("Withdrawing " + withdrawlAmount + " from account1 balance....");
   account2.withdraw(withdrawlAmount);


  System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2f%n", account1.getName(), account1.getBalance());
   System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2f%n%n", account2.getName(), account2.getBalance());
```

}
}

Comment: use System.exit(0); in case repeat equals 'N'

Comment: will do, thanks! What about being able to repeat each question so the user can do as many withdraws as they want before moving on? Any ideas?

Comment: use while like you did already